# куда смотреть когда сайт медленно работает?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, веб-сервер, puma

Проблемы с доступностью сайта. Иногда сайт начинает медленно работать, иногда падает вообще (502 bad gateway).
Во время таких вот падений смотрю `htop`. Чаще всего (**но не всегда**) он показывает большую загрузку процессора, больше всего загружает **puma cluster worker**.

1) Проблема может быть в коде, например в запросах к БД?
2) Куда смотреть, когда сайт медленно работает/упал? (я ориентируюсь на htop и логи nginx'a в основном )

- Всегда помогает `kill -9 ID_puma_cluster_worker` (даже если загрузки процессора нет)
- Ночами в основном нормально.
- По выходным тоже чаще всего все нормально.
- Ориентируюсь на рассылку от [ping-admin.ru](http://ping-admin.ru)
- Есть множество soap запросов

Comment: Пихайте таймеры в код и печатайте время выполнения различного кода в логи, чо. Проблема может быть в чём угодно, измеряйте

Comment: Подключите NewRelic и посмотрите какие запросы обеспечивают максимальную нагрузку и какова структура запроса, на что тратится время (ruby, база данных, внешние запросы и т.п.). Он на интервал 1 сутки бесплатен - вполне хватит для отладки.